# Is there a way to associate to a file the website URL where it was downloaded from?

Tags: ubuntu, download, url, metadata

I'm using Ubuntu and trying to find a way to associate the URL of the website where a file was downloaded to that file. According to what I've researched so far the URL can be stored using extended attributes, but my problem is how to know/intercept that URL of the site where the file was downloaded.

I've also found the following link - http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/CommonExtendedAttributes/
 - but I don't understand if this is still in development or can be downloaded and installed.

Comment: It looks like a job for the program which actually downloads the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a proxy server like `squid`, the data will be available in the access log.  The access log get rotated and deleted eventually.  The data can be easilty matched to the downloaded file as long as the access log is available, and the filename used to save it matches the URL.  If the file is cached, the cache header will contain the source for the file.

`html` files may contain meta data which may indicate the host the page was downloaded from.

It would be much easier if the downloading program where write the extended attribute at down load time.  I don't know of any that do.

Tools like `wget` may store files in a directory structure named using the domain name from the URL.  This could be used to populate the extended attribute.

What is the use case for gathering this data?

Comment: Well I'm trying to develop an application that stores the url of the website where a file was downloaded in its extended attributes. Just thought it would be interesting to have this information associated to each downloaded file :)

Comment: @user2900870 If the application is doing the downloading, then it should be trivial for it to add the attribute.  Other applications generally, don't keep that information around where it is trivially accessible.

Comment: it's not the application I'm developing that downloads the file, this application should somehow intercept the url of the website when the file is saved in the computer, but for what I'm reading I should reconsider my approach